# How to use fluentApi to manage nested relations?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, dictionary, fluent

I have a User Model

```
public class User {
    public Guid IdGuid {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public virtual List<User> Friends {get;set;}
}
```

And I have  second model

```
public class UserFriendship{
    public Guid FriendShipIdGuid {get;set;}
    public Guid UserIdGuid {get;set;}
    public Guid FriendIdGuid {get;set;}
}
```

I have FluentApi code `OnModelcreating` in context.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.Friends).WithMany().Map(c => {
    c.MapLeftKey("UserIdGuid"); 
    c.MapRightKey("FriendIdGuid");
    c.ToTable("UserFriendship");
    });
```

Problem : I already have a `UserFriendship` class model. And I want to create relation about users to this model. And I am doing it with FluentApi.

But after FluentApi code executed, `FriendShipIdGuid` is removed from `UserFriendship` Table.

I need to create one to many relation for Users, and save it to table `UserFriendship` and map it already existing class model name with `UserFriendship` which element of dbset.
Can you help me please ?

As a summary, I already have `UserFriendship` class. And this class contains `FrientshipGuidId` (Key), `UserIdGuid`, `FriendIdGuid`.
I need to map, `User` class one to many to itself. 
And I want to save this relation on `UserFriendship` class.
And I want to use `Userfriendship` as dbset also.

I have

```
public DbSet<UserFriendship> Friendships { get;set; }
```

in my context.

I am using FluentApi `ToTable` function to create one to many relation table.
But FluentApi code delete `FriendshipIdGuid` field.

Comment: Are you trying to use Code First with an existing table?

Comment: @mostruash Yes. Existing table creating by fluent. But i need to use this UserFriendship  as dbset also. I will use this friendship data for User class property. This property is List<User> Friends . Is that possible ? I need to generate User.Friends list from UserFriendship table and i need also use UserFriendship as DbSet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. You can't use a `List<UserFriendship>` in `User` class either because sometimes a User is a user and other times a User is a friend, unless you have duplicates in your `UserFriendship` table like this:

```
Friendship table:          |
----------------------------

User / Friend
-------------
  A  /   B
  B  /   A
-------------
```

First change `User` and `UserFriendship` classes as follows:

```
class UserFriendship 
{
    public Guid FriendShipIdGuid {get;set;}
    public Guid UserIdGuid {get;set;}
    public Guid FriendIdGuid {get;set;}

    public User User {get;set;}
    public User Friend {get;set;}
}

class User 
{
    public Guid IdGuid {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

    // Only if you will allow duplicates in UserFriendship
    public virtual List<UserFriendship> Friendships {get;set;}
}
```

I don't remember the exact syntax/methods of Fluent API but you will get the idea:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
  .HasKey(u => u.IdGuid)
  .ToTable("User");

modelBuilder.Entity<UserFriendship>()
  .HasKey(uf => uf.FriendShipIdGuid)
  .ToTable("UserFriendship");

modelBuilder.Entity<UserFriendship>()
  .HasRequired(uf => uf.User)
  .WithMany(u => u.Friendships)       // Only if you allow duplicates
  //.WithMany()                         // Otherwise
  .HasForeignKey(uf => uf.UserIdGuid);

modelBuilder.Entity<UserFriendShip>()
   .HasRequired(uf => uf.Friend)
   .WithMany()
   .HasForeignKey(uf => uf.FriendIdGuid);
```

Comment: what do you mean when you said duplicates ? for example  1 friends with 2 and   2 friend with 1 . Do  you mean that ? Another think, you commented //.WithMany()  . If i dont want to use duplicates, should i use delete this .WithMany() line ?

Comment: Yes, I mean that. If you don't want to use duplicates, use `.WithMany()`. Delete `List<UserFriendship> Friendships` from `User` class. I suggest you to use duplicates. It will make your life easier. Please accept as answer if this helped you.

Comment: I could nt solve it with fluentApi :( Trying another ways. Thanks for help.